# Concurrent UDP connection limit in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, sockets, udp

I wrote a `server in c` which receive `UDP` data from client in port `X`. I have used `Epoll(non block)` socket for `UDP` listening and has only one thread as worker. Pseudo code is following:

```
on_data_receive(socket){
    process(); //take 2-4 millisecond
    send_response(socket);
}
```

But when I send `5000 concurrent` (using thread) request server miss `5-10%` request. on_data_receive() never called for 5-10% request. I am testing in local network so you can assume there is no packet loss. My question is why on_data_receive didn't call for some request? What is the connection limit for socket? With the increase of concurrent request loss ratio also increase.

**Note: I used random sleep upto 200 millisecond before sending the request to server.**

Comment: You can never assume no packet loss for UDP, even on a local network.

Comment: What's the output of `cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max` ?  5000 threads and 5000 connections might use up memory?

Comment: what is the second parameter on the call to the system function: `listen()`?  In general( embedded Linux actually queues UDP packets) if the receiver is not ready to read a UDP packet before the next one arrives, the first one is lost/ overlayed by the next UDP packet.  Is the code actually creating a new connection for each packet?  If so, that will greatly reduce the available through put

Comment: Please post actual code.  a modern computer should be able to keep up with a UDP connection that averages 100msec between packets

Comment: @Yun-ChihChen I have only one thread. cat returns 780670.

Comment: There is no such thing as a UDP connection.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no 'connection' for UDP. All packets are just sent between peers, and the OS does some magic buffering to avoid packet loss to some degree.

But when too many packets arrive, or if the receiving application is too slow reading the packets, some packets get dropped without notice. This is not an error.

For example Linux has a UDP receive buffer which is about 128k by default (I think). You can probably change that, but it is unlikely to solve the systematic problem that UDP may expose packet loss.

With UDP there is no congestion control like there is for TCP. The raw artifacts of the underlying transport (Ethernet, local network) are exposed. Your 5000 senders get probably more CPU time in total than your receiver, and so they can send more packets than the receiver can receive. With UDP senders do *not* get blocked (e.g. in sendto()) when the receiver cannot keep up receiving the packets. With UDP the sender always needs to control and limit the data rate explicitly. There is no back pressure from the network side (*).

(*) Theoretically there is no back pressure in UDP. But on some operating systems (e.g. Linux) you can observe that there *is* back pressure (at least to some degree) when sending for example over a local Ethernet. The OS blocks in sendto() when the network driver of the physical network interface reports that it is busy (or that its buffer is full). But this back pressure stops working when the local network adapter cannot determine the network 'being busy' for the whole network path. See also "Ethernet flow control (Pause Frames)". Through this the sending side can block the sending application even when the receive-buffer on the receiving side is full. This explains why often there seems to be a UDP back-pressure like a TCP back pressure, although there is nothing in the UDP protocol to support back pressure.